# sh404sef and update to Joomla 3.6.2

Tags: joomla

I'm working on a Joomla website that was handed over to me (I'm new with all Joomla things). My problem is that after updating to Joomla 3.6.2, the sh404sef extension is causing a lot of 404s (it worked fine in Joomla 3.5.1). I do not know if the same problem is also with 3.6, because I didn't do the update.

It looks like sh404sef has a problem with multilingual content. On pages where there is only one language the extension is working fine. Did anyone come across the same problem?

I know that the best solution is to use backup, but as I mentioned already the update was not made by me and there is not a backup file.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of sh404SEF? It may be best to escalate this question to the sh404SEF developer.

Comment: yes I am, and also contacted weeblr with this problem, tried their suggestion  and it did not work also. their replay: "Yes, this a known issue caused by a change in Joomla 3.6.1. what you need to do is rest the initial ordering of system plugins on your site, and put the language filter system plugin before the sh404sef one." problem is that when I change ordering of plugins they do not take new positions. I also tried to change ordering in DB, then ordering is as I want but problem is still there. I only thought if someone else has the same problem and may any suggestion how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue caused by Joomla 3.6.2 is that the ordering of the language filter routing rules is not the same, on a small number of multilingual sites. As properly explained on support, you have to put the plugins in the right orders, using the Joomla drag and drop feature, on the Joomla plugins manager. This is enabled by clicking on the small icon in the header of the order column. If you don't enable the drag and drop mode, the new ordering indeed won't stick.

If you reordered the plugins in the database, and they also show in the correct order in the Joomla plugins manager, then this will fix the problem. It does for all the sites affected by this issue in the last few days.
If not, I would encourage you to go back to our support, we can probably do the re-ordering for you, if granted access.

Rgds